# How to set DSCP field for IGMP join in Windows OS?

Tags: c++, windows, networking

I cannot find any working method to set DSCP different than 0 in Windows 7+.
Windows Policy-based QoS allows to do it only for UDP and TCP protocols. It is strange that I can set it for UDP (multicast traffic), but cannot set it for corresponding IGMP join.

I tried to verify in mutliple places (see -IPProtocolMatchCondition switch):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netqos/new-netqospolicy?view=win10-ps

Or here (interesting comment for IP_TOS : Do not use)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738586(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: IGMP is a link-local protocol, so setting the DSCP doesn't really make sense. It is possible to route some multicast packets using multicast routing, but there are link-local multicasts that cannot be routed. IGMP cannot be routed.

Comment: Thank you for clarification.